# Generating <td> by 2 for loops by comparing 2 JavaScript arrays

Tags: javascript

I want the my data table like in screenshot 1. But generating it by 2 for loops creating data table in screenshot 2.

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

my code:

```
for (a = 0; a < sem_course_code.length; a++) {
for (c = 0; c < applied_courses.length; c++) {
    if (sem_course_code[a] == applied_courses[c]) {
        td_content += "<td>" + applied_courses[c] + "</td>";
        continue;
    } else {
        td_content += "<td>--</td>";
    }

  }
}
alert(td_content);
$('#exam_marks_tbl tr:last').append(td_content);
```

Please help.

Edit:
for Number 1 student arrays are as below:

```
sem_course_code = [CRS02,CRS04,CRS03,CRS01];
applied_courses = [CRS02,CRS01];
```

Comment: can you share a fiddle or working snippet demonstrating your issue?

Comment: Working code in a fiddle would be great as we need the data in applied_courses and other variables

Comment: please provide a full working example

Comment: @js_noob Please check the edit.

Answer (score 0):

This is the quickest thing I can come up with, Let me know if You want to modify anything.

```js
let sem_course_code = ['CRS02','CRS04','CRS03','CRS01'];
let applied_courses = ['CRS02','CRS01'];
let td_content = "<tr>";

let applied_courses_modified =new Array(sem_course_code.length).fill('--')
for(let i=0;i<applied_courses.length;i++){
  applied_courses_modified[sem_course_code.indexOf(applied_courses[i])] = applied_courses[i]
}
for(let j=0;j<applied_courses_modified.length;j++){
  td_content += "<td>" + applied_courses_modified[j] + "</td>";
}
td_content += "</tr>"
alert(applied_courses_modified)
alert(td_content)
document.getElementById('exam_marks_tbl').innerHTML = td_content
```

```html
<table border="1px" >
  <tbody id="exam_marks_tbl">
  
  </tbody>
</table>
```